# soapUI: Running testcases unattended at scheduled time

Tags: soapui

Is it possible in soapUI pro to run the testcases unattended at a scheduled time. 
For example at night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

soapUI comes with a command line runner (`testrunner.bat` or `testrunner.sh`). It takes a number of arguments to control which tests to run, etc.

See the documentation here: http://soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html

On Windows you can automate the execution with the [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Schedule-a-task) and on Unix for example with the [cron job scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).